# How to generate a series of real random numbers in Java?

Tags: java, random

The java documentation said java.util.Random only produces pseudo-random numbers. Is there a way to generate real random numbers in Java?

Comment: A computer is a deterministic machine. Unless you have a special hardware piece that isn't deterministic and can therefor be used to create actual randomness, pseudo randomness is everything your computer will ever be able to produce. The good news is that for almost all cases pseudo random numbers are just as good as actual random numbers and you seem to be trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: You can use java.security.SecureRandom for "cryptographically strong" random numbers at the cost of some performance. However, these are (probably) still pseudo-random numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
There is no way.
With your computer, you can generate only pseudo-random numbers.
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#"True"_vs._pseudo-random_numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#%22True%22_vs._pseudo-random_numbers)

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right I can only generate pseudo-random number with my computer. I was wondering whether for two runs whether there will be any correlation. I looked up the documentation, it says the java random number was generated based on the seed of the current system time. So the pseudo random number should satisfy my needs.